# Java Run method entered by user

Tags: java

I want to have a text field and run whatever the user enters into it. So if the user types in,
`aPackage.AClass.aMethod(parms)`, it would run that method in the package, class and with those parameters. Is this possible?
The reason I want this is so that I can debug my code and put the program into "developer mode" and be able to execute any command.

Comment: generally, it's bad practice to let the user access the code. Parse the text into an array of Strings, and then use if statements (or a tokenizer) to read the arguments and run commands.

Comment: Yes, but not really trivially. There might be some libraries out there to help, but if not you'd parse it and use the reflection API. You might find this more desirable in any case because you could blacklist certain packages/methods/etc which could let a user cause mischief.

Comment: Added reason for this question

Comment: For debugging purposes, an integrated [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you know classname, methodname, input params types then using reflection this can be achieved. Here is a small code snippet for the same:

```
            //load the AppTest at runtime
    Class cls = Class.forName("aPackage.AClass");
    Object obj = cls.newInstance();

    //call the printIt method
    Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("aMethod", noparams);
    method.invoke(obj, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  Using the Java Reflection API ([tutorial on docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)), you can access classes and their methods by name.  A potential problem if you don’t know the type of the arguments are overloaded methods.  And be aware that letting the user execute random code is a potential security issue.